# Как добавить или удалить элемент массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, javascript-faq

Есть массив, например:

```
var m = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

1. Как добавить элемент в массив?
2. Как удалить элемент массива?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Добавление

- [`Array.prototype.push(element1, ..., elementN)`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.7) добавляет элемент(ы) **в конец** массива. Возвращает новую длину массива.

  ```
  m.push(6);
  > 6        // m равно [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  m.push(7, 8, 9);
  > 9        // m равно [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.unshift(element1, ..., elementN)`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.13) добавляет элемент(ы) **в начало** массива. Возвращает новую длину массива.

  ```
  m.unshift(0);
  > 6           // m равно [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  m.unshift(3, 2, 1);
  > 9           // m равно [3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.12) изменяет содержимое массива, удаляя элементы и/или добавляя новые. Возвращает массив удалённых элементов.

  ```
  m.splice(2, 0, 2.5);
  > []                 // m равно [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 5]
  m.splice(5, 0, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75);
  > []                 // m равно [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.25, 4.5, 4.75, 5]  
  m.splice(5, 3, 4.33, 4.66);
  > [4.25, 4.5, 4.75]  // m равно [1, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.33, 4.66, 5]
  ```
- Можно изменить свойсто `.length` массива, чтобы добавлять элементы `undefined` в конец.

  ```
  m.length = 7;
  > 7           // m равно [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, undefined, undefined]
  ```

### Удаление

- [`Array.prototype.pop()`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.6) **удаляет последний элемент** массива. Возвращает удалённый элемент.

  ```
  m.pop();
  > 5      // m равно [1, 2, 3, 4]
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.shift()`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.9) **удаляет первый элемент** массива. Возвращает удалённый элемент.

  ```
  m.shift();
  > 1      // m равно [2, 3, 4, 5]
  ```
- [`Array.prototype.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])`<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)[<sup>[спецификация]</sup>](http://es5.javascript.ru/x15.4.html#x15.4.4.12) изменяет содержимое массива, удаляя элементы и/или добавляя новые. Возвращает массив удалённых элементов.

  ```
  m.splice(2, 1);
  > [3]           // m равно [1, 2, 4, 5]
  m.splice(1, 2);
  > [2, 4]        // m равно [1, 5]
  ```
- Можно изменить свойсто `.length` массива, чтобы удалять последние элементы.

  ```
  m.length = 3;
  > 3            // m равно [1, 2, 3]
  ```

Comment: но ведь при изменении свойства `length` элементы **не** добавляются

Answer (score 0):

```
// сам массив
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

// элемент, который хотим удалить/вставить в массив
let element = 55;

// поиск существования элемента
let isset_element = arr.find(item => item == element);

if(isset_element){
  arr.forEach(function(item, i){
    // ищем вхождение в массив
    // элемента, совпадающего с введенным
    if(item == element){
      // удаление элемента по индексу
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    }
  });
} else {
  // добавление элемента
  arr.push(element);
}
console.log('result', arr);
```